# detached entity passed to persist: JPA inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a class Bus which inherits from Vehicle. It's a JPA Single table inheritance (the discriminator column is TYPE : "B" for bus).
When I try to persist a Bus, i get this error.
what can be the reason? thanks

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.enseirb.it307.tp.entities.VehicleStatus
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:838)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.cascade(CascadingActions.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at
```

code causing the error :

```
//Bus
Bus bus1 = BusTools.getSampleBus1();
createdToulouseOrg.addVehicle(bus1);
logger.info("insert Bus " + bus1);
Vehicle createdBus1 = vehicleDao.insertVehicle(bus1);
```

the insertVehicle method uses entitymanager.persist

```
@Override
public Vehicle insertVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(vehicle);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    return vehicle;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code causing this error.

Comment: I added the code causing the error

Comment: No, that's the call to your DAO, not the actual persisting.

Comment: I added the dao code

Comment: What does `createdToulouseOrg.addVehicle(bus1)` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the log, the Vehicle contains an association to a `VehicleStatus` entity or entities.

The 'detached entity passed to persist' error is given because the persist operation is cascaded to `VehicleStatus` too.

The easiest fix is to call `merge` instead of `persist`:

```
@Override
public Vehicle insertVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    vehicle = entityManager.merge(vehicle);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    return vehicle;
}
```